# webpack less error, it can't resolve .ttf and woff2 files from uikit

Tags: less, webpack

I'm really newbie with webpack, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, I wish use [uikit](http://getuikit.com/docs/documentation_less-sass.html) and less with webpack, I've installed the respective loaders like url-loader,file-loader,less-loader

and include in the webpack config

```
loaders: [{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')
 },
 {
test: /\.less$/,
loader: 'style!css!less'
},
{
       test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
       loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"
 },
{
       test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
       loader: "file-loader"
   },
   {
       test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.wav$|\.mp3$/,
       loader: "file-loader"
   }
   /*,  <----I ALSO TRY WITH THIS CONFIG....
     { test: /\.woff$/,   loader: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
     { test: /\.ttf$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
     { test: /\.eot$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
     { test: /\.svg$/,    loader: "file-loader" }*/
```

]

I include my less file in the entry point of my js file

```
 require("!css!less!../less/main.less")
```

and my less file looks like

@import "../bower_components/uikit/less/uikit.less";

html{
  background-color: red;
}

the directory [image]

when I try run the console shows this:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../bower_components/uikit/less/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot in /home/yo/Downloads/proj/scalaPROJ/activatorPRJ/finatra-seed/react-hot-boilerplate/less
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less 6:77369-77440 6:77463-77534

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../bower_components/uikit/less/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 in /home/yo/Downloads/proj/scalaPROJ/activatorPRJ/finatra-seed/react-hot-boilerplate/less
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less 6:77586-77659

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../bower_components/uikit/less/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff in /home/yo/Downloads/proj/scalaPROJ/activatorPRJ/finatra-seed/react-hot-boilerplate/less
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less 6:77690-77762

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../bower_components/uikit/less/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf in /home/yo/Downloads/proj/scalaPROJ/activatorPRJ/finatra-seed/react-hot-boilerplate/less
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./less/main.less 6:77794-77865
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

hope the errors will be much more clear for you and can help me,thank so much

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recommend you to write loaders in a short way

**webpack.config.js**

```
loaders: [
... other loaders
{
    test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]'
}
```

Don't forget

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

And checkout variable @icon-font-path it should be

**/bower_components/uikit/less/core/icon.less**

```
"../../fonts";
```

Comment: thank so much,it works after change the file icon.less

Comment: The important point here is the '&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]'. This tells your application where to look for the files. I had this same issue, and for a while was mistake that the '&name=' was where webpack would add the files. Instead, it's where to look for the files. This was filed and closed as an issue for webpack: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader/issues/32. Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: how about /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/ to support the rogue ?v=1.1.1 version params