# Webpack build fails CSS fonts

Tags: css, webpack, webfonts

I am getting errors like

```
ERROR in ./src/fonts/VistaSansOT-Light.ttf
Module parse failed: /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/goldbell-client/src/fonts/VistaSansOT-Light.ttf Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/css-loader?minimize!./~/sass-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./src/css/custom.css 6:876-917
```

I think its something to do with loading of the font files. My webpack config is below. I tried using both url and file loaders but failed

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint'
      }
    ],

    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: [
          'style',
          'css',
          'sass',
          'postcss'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate',
          'babel'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loaders: [
          'url'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    // new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    })
  ],
  postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  entry: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`
};
```

Comment: This looks OK at first glance - are you sure Webpack is using this config?

Comment: Would this answer help you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493716/webpack-less-error-it-cant-resolve-ttf-and-woff2-files-from-uikit