# VueJS + AT UIKIT: Failed to compile

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I scaffolded a project using `vue init webpack-simple`. I am hoping to use the [AT-UIKIT](https://at-ui.github.io/at-ui/#/en) component library but I was met with the following compile error from webpack:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/at-ui-style/css/fonts/feather.ttf?t=1501829003743
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/at-ui-style/css/at.css 6:71718-71764
 @ ./node_modules/at-ui-style/css/at.css
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Here is my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import AtComponents from 'at-ui'
import 'at-ui-style'    // Import CSS

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

I am new to VueJS and webpack. Am I to install a certain loader to fix this? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493716/webpack-less-error-it-cant-resolve-ttf-and-woff2-files-from-uikit

Answer (score 0):

you forget [install](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use) plugin.

add code in you main.js:

```
Vue.use(AtComponents)
```